# How to call vue method inside vuex module?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules, vue-property-decorator, vuex-module-decorators

Assume that we need the single modal dialog with dynamic content.
To access to this modal's API from any component, we can use below Vuex store.
Below solution has been checked in real project and working fine:

```js
import store from "@Store/store";
import { Action, Mutation, VuexModule, Module, getModule } from "vuex-module-decorators";

type UnifiedModalDialogOptions = {
  targetContentID: string;
  mainTitle?: string;
};


@Module({
  name: "VUEX_MODULE/COMPONENTS/UNIFIED_MODAL",
  store,
  dynamic: true,
  namespaced: true
})
export default class UnifiedModalDialogService extends VuexModule {

  private _displayFlag: boolean = false;
  private _activeContent: string | null = null;
  private _mainTitle: string | null = null;

  @Action
  public displayDialog({
    targetContentID,
    mainTitle
  }: UnifiedModalDialogOptions): void {

    this.setActiveContentID(targetContentID);
    this.setSizingMode(sizingMode);

    if (!isUndefined(mainTitle)) {
      this.setMainTitle(mainTitle);
    }

    if (!isUndefined(sizingCustomCSS_Class)) {
      this.setCustomSizingCSS_Class(sizingCustomCSS_Class);
    }

    this.setDisplayFlag(true);
  }

  @Mutation
  public dismiss(): void {
    this._displayFlag = false;
    this._activeContent = null;
    this._mainTitle = null;
  }

  public get displayFlag(): boolean { return this._displayFlag; }
  public get mainTitle(): string | null { return this._mainTitle; }
  public get activeContentID(): string | null { return this._activeContent; }


  @Mutation
  private setDisplayFlag(newFlagValue: boolean): void {
    this._displayFlag = newFlagValue;
  }

  @Mutation
  private setActiveContentID(targetContentID: string): void {
    this._activeContent = targetContentID;
  }

  @Mutation
  private setMainTitle(newMainTitle: string): void {
    this._mainTitle = newMainTitle;
  }
}
```

Now what if we need to call some additional function when closing modal?
For instance, in below example, when we click "close" button of modal or click the dim underlay under modal, we need to utilize the account editing by `finishAccountEditing` method:

```js
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { getModule } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import UnifiedModalDialogService
    from "@Components:SharedSingletons/UnifiedModalDialog/UnifiedModalDialogService.vuex";

@Component
export default class AccountsManagementPage extends Vue {

  private onClickEditAccountButton(targetAccount: Account): void {

    private inputtedAccountName: string = "";
    private inputtedEmail: string = "";

    this.inputtedAccountName = targetAccount.name;
    this.inputtedEmail = targetAccount.email;

    getModule(UnifiedModalDialogService).displayDialog({
      targetContentID: this.ACCOUNT_ADDING_AND_EDITING_MODAL_DIALOG_ID,
      mainTitle: StaticStrings.modalDialogsTitles.accountEditing,
      sizingMode: UnifiedModalDialogService.SizingModes.fixedMaximalWidth,
    });
  }

  private finishAccountEditing() void {
    this.inputtedAccountName = "";
    this.inputtedEmail = "";
  }
}
```

Please note that the modal dialog component is not the child component, so we cant's access to it by reference.

### Attempts and experiments

The logically right solution is to pass the function to vuex module and remember it:

```js
@Component
export default class AccountsManagementPage extends Vue {

  private onClickEditAccountButton(targetAccount: Account): void {

    private inputtedAccountName: string = "";
    private inputtedEmail: string = "";

    this.inputtedAccountName = targetAccount.name;
    this.inputtedEmail = targetAccount.email;

    getModule(UnifiedModalDialogService).displayDialog({
      targetContentID: this.ACCOUNT_ADDING_AND_EDITING_MODAL_DIALOG_ID,
      mainTitle: StaticStrings.modalDialogsTitles.accountEditing,
      sizingMode: UnifiedModalDialogService.SizingModes.fixedMaximalWidth,
      // added ↓
      onClose: this.finishAccountEditing.bind(this)
    });
  }

  private finishAccountEditing() void {
    this.inputtedAccountName = "";
    this.inputtedEmail = "";
  }
}
```

Now I'll try to call it inside `UnifiedModalDialogService` module (just for experiment - inside `displayDialog`):

```js
@Action
public displayDialog({
  targetContentID,
  sizingMode,
  sizingCustomCSS_Class,
  mainTitle,
  onClose
}: UnifiedModalDialogOptions): void {

  onClose();

  // ...
}
```

The result is unexpected:

```
index.js?0da5:363 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ERR_ACTION_ACCESS_UNDEFINED: 
Are you trying to access this.someMutation() or this.someGetter inside an @Action? 
That works only in dynamic modules. 
If not dynamic use this.context.commit("mutationName", payload) and this.context.getters["getterName"]
Error: Could not perform action displayDialog
```

At least two strange moments:

> Are you trying to access this.someMutation() or this.someGetter inside an @Action?

No.

> That works only in dynamic modules.

My module is dynamic:

```js
@Module({
  name: "VUEX_MODULE/COMPONENTS/UNIFIED_MODAL",
  store,
  dynamic: true,
  namespaced: true
})
export default class UnifiedModalDialogService extends VuexModule {
  //...
}
```

The next experiment is delegating `onClose` calling to static method.

```js
export default class UnifiedModalDialogService extends VuexModule {

  @Action
  public displayDialog({
    targetContentID,
    sizingMode,
    sizingCustomCSS_Class,
    mainTitle,
    onClose
  }: UnifiedModalDialogOptions): void {

    UnifiedModalDialogService._onClose(onClose);

    this.setActiveContentID(targetContentID);
    this.setSizingMode(sizingMode);

    if (!isUndefined(mainTitle)) {
      this.setMainTitle(mainTitle);
    }

    if (!isUndefined(sizingCustomCSS_Class)) {
      this.setCustomSizingCSS_Class(sizingCustomCSS_Class);
    }

    this.setDisplayFlag(true);
  }
  
  private static _onClose(implementation: () => unknown): void {
    implementation();
  }
}
```

The result is identical:

```
index.js?0da5:363 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ERR_ACTION_ACCESS_UNDEFINED
```

Herewith, generally the calling of static methods is possible:

```js
@Module({
  name: "VUEX_MODULE/COMPONENTS/UNIFIED_MODAL",
  store,
  dynamic: true,
  namespaced: true
})
export default class UnifiedModalDialogService extends VuexModule {

  @Action
  public displayDialog({
    targetContentID,
    sizingMode,
    sizingCustomCSS_Class,
    mainTitle,
    onClose
  }: UnifiedModalDialogOptions): void {

    UnifiedModalDialogService.staticMethodExample();

    // ...
  }


  private static staticMethodExample(): void {
    console.log("Im am vuex module static method!");
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why a Modal component will need Vuex or API ? Can't you just have a default slot and a `value` prop to toggle the modal on/off ? And the parent component will inject whatever it needs into the slot.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, thank you for the comment. I am not sure about understood you correctly, but does the approach that you are suggesting is multiple modal dialogs per application? In this question, I am considering SINGLE modal dialog per application. "And the parent component will inject whatever it needs into the slot." - what if target component is not parent of modal?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting multiple dialogs/modals as an (subjectively) simpler method compared to a single dialog with an API and Vuex store. It is okay if the idea does not work for your case.

Comment: `ERR_ACTION_ACCESS_UNDEFINED` is just "general" [wrapper error](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/blob/7bf752f3e066e27289bf1de1fe84ebfdcd8f5c0c/src/action.ts#L49). [Configure vuex-module-decorators](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators#configuration-1) to throw original exception and update your question with full text and stacktrace...

Comment: @MichalLevý, Thank you for the comment. I'm very sorry, but I temporary lost access to my application, so I can't check it out right now. I'll post the information that you requested ASAP.